# choose a db connection pool

Tags: connection-pooling, c3p0, proxool, apache-commons-dbcp

we want to use a db connection pool in our applicationl,however thear are so many open soure pools,like dbcp,c3p0,proxool and etc.

I have no idea which is better,any one have some experience about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the one that is built into your Java EE app server if you're using one.  That's should be sufficient.  Why add another dependency?

I'd recommend using DBCP from Apache.  It'll work just fine for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

As author of BoneCP (http://jolbox.com), I invite you to have a look at the benchmark section on that site and judge for yourself.

W